# Kotlin - combining flows

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

In my viewModel I have:

```
    private val setEntitiesList = mutableStateListOf<Exercise>()

    val exercisesFromDB = exerciseDao.getAllExercisesWithSetNo(trainingId)

    val exercises =
        exercisesFromDB.combine(setEntitiesList.asFlow()) { exercises, setEntitiesList ->
            Pair(exercises, setEntitiesList)
        }.mapLatest { (exercises, setEntitiesList) ->
            //I am altering exercises list here
            exercises
        }
```

In my fragment I have:

```
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
                addTrainingViewModel.exercises.collectLatest {
                    exercisesAdapter.submitList(it)
                }
            }
        }
```

It doesnt work. Nothing is collected in fragment

If I change in fragment to collect "addTrainingViewModel.exercisesFromDB" it works - values are emited and collected.

What I would like to achieve: new list of exercises is emitted when setEntitiesList or exercisesFromDB are changed and I am able to do sth with a list of exercises before it is emitted

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `setEntitiesList` variable is of type `Iterable`. In that case when you convert it to `Flow` like `setEntitiesList.asFlow()` you create a [**cold Flow**](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/as-flow.html), it means that when you add new elements to the `setEntitiesList` iterable they won't be emitted to the combined `Flow`.

On the other hand, by calling `addTrainingViewModel.exercisesFromDB` you get a hot `Flow`, so when you tested it separately you got the right result.

So you can't use a converted iterable object `setEntitiesList` as hot `Flow`. You need somehow to rewrite your logic and use a hot `Flow` instead of cold `Flow`. You can use [`MutableSharedFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/index.html) for that. The code will be something like the following:

```
private val setEntitiesListFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Exercise>(extraBufferCapacity = 64)

val exercisesFromDB = exerciseDao.getAllExercisesWithSetNo(trainingId)

val exercises =
    exercisesFromDB.combine(setEntitiesListFlow) { exercises, setEntitiesList ->
        Pair(exercises, setEntitiesList)
    }.mapLatest { (exercises, setEntitiesList) ->
        //I am altering exercises list here
        exercises
    }


// somewhere else in your code emitting Exercise:

setEntitiesListFlow.tryEmit(Exercise(...))
```

Comment: This answer is generally correct about the main point, but I believe hot and cold have much different meanings and this could be misleading. Cold flow is one that does not do anything in the background, it is inactive until collected, it produces items on demand. Hot flows could run in the background and/or produce items even if nobody collects them. Therefore, the problem here is not caused by flow being hot or cold, but by the fact that `Iterable` can't be observed for changes.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Your answer was helpful. There was also another problem with my code.  "val exercisesFromDB = exerciseDao.getAllExercisesWithSetNo(trainingId)" - it was emiting values before I combine it with second flow. That is why it was working when I was collecting "exercisesFromDb" but not when "exercises"